# Google JS SDK - my contacts search

Tags: javascript, api, sdk, google-plus

I need to search for contacts in my circles using a phrase, which can be name (or part of it) or email.

I am using the Google client SDK, I tried the 'plus' library, using the 'search' function I get a global search results of users (not related to me) and using the 'list' function I get just the people who use my app which is too narrow.

I would like to search in my contacts/circles

```
gapi.client.plus.people.search({
   'query': phrase
})

gapi.client.plus.people.list({
  'userId' : 'me',
  'collection' : 'visible'
})
```

Comment: You should change your title to make clear is Google Plus JS SDK. Anyway, in this moment, appears that query for specific contact names or emails is not possible, according the documentation. An ugly workaround will be, of course, get all contacts and filter by yourself.

Comment: Yes, that what I just did. The ugliest part is that the JS client SDK doesn't support the Contacts V3 API so I had to ajax it myself